# Save only some rows in SQL Server full text search catalog

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Is there a way to save only some records to full text catalog? For example we have a table taxablePerson with columns

```
Id, VatNumber, Name, Street, ....other fields ...,
RecCreatedOn, RecCreatedBy, RecModifiedOn, RecModifiedBy, RecActive
```

Column **RecActive** means if this record is valid. Records don't get deleted, they are deleted by setting RecActive = 0. When I search I run:

```
SELECT TOP 50 *
FROM TaxPerson.TaxablePerson AS tp
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(TaxPerson.TaxablePerson, (Name), @find) AS key_table
   ON key_table.[key] = tp.id
WHERE tp.RecActive = 1
ORDER BY key_table.rank DESC;
```

Performance is very good by not applying inner join. Is there a way to put only records which have RecActive = 1 to full text search catalog. This would be a great feature of ms sql fts.

Comment: I hope, this is what you are looking for. Filtered indexes https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/introduction-to-sql-server-filtered-indexes/ ?

Comment: @Aditya this would be solution, but [full text search index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) doesn't support filtering, something like `create fulltext index on TaxPerson.TaxablePerson (Name) key index Id on TaxPersonFTS_Catalog WHERE TaxPerson.RecActive = 1`. Thanks anyway I didn't know till now that you can create filtered indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create **a VIEW** and then add a fulltext index to the view.